# How to select top 3 dates SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure..

```
id    title   Date
1     Abc     14 Nov 2016
2     Abc     14 Nov 2016
3     Abc     13 Nov 2016
4     Abc     13 Nov 2016
5     Abc     13 Nov 2016
6     Abc     12 Nov 2016
7     Abc     12 Nov 2016
8     Abc     11 Nov 2016
9     Abc     11 Nov 2016
```

How to select data of top 3 dates only.. .
means data of columns have date as `14,13, 12.`

or may be next 3 dates.. like only data of `13,12,11` or only `12,11`

NOt getting any idea how to make it.. using `MYSQL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the top 3 dates.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM YourTable AS a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Date
      FROM YourTable
      ORDER BY Date DESC
      LIMIT 3) AS b
ON a.Date = b.Date
```

Comment: Not only top 3 .. some general query .. to get may be next three dates like 13,12,11 or 13 and 12 only

Comment: You can replace `LIMIT 3` with whatever criteria you want, like `LIMIT 3,1` to start with the next highest.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM TableName ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: this will only give dates.. not the data .. and only 1 entry per date.